# jQuery checking and unchecking checkboxes

Tags: jquery, jquery-attributes

I have to check and uncheck the checkboxes. But it is not working well.

Example: When the status is active on the 1st load:

- Unchecking the checkboxes into inactive (Works fine)
- Checking it back again to make it active (Not working, stays uncheck)

Example: WHen the status is inactive on the 1st load:

- Checking the checkboxes into active (Works fine)
- Unchecking the checkboxes into inactive (Works fine)
- Checking it back again to make it active (Not working, stays uncheck)

Here is my sample code:

```
var statusCheck = $('.status-box');

$.ajax({
    url: 'sample/url',
    type: 'POST',
    data: {
        user_id: ids,
        status: statusVal
    },
    success: function (response) {
        if (response == 'ok') {
            $.each(statusCheck, function () {
                var _this = $(this);

                if (_this.is(':checked')) {
                    _this.removeAttr('checked');
                } else {
                    _this.attr('checked', '');
                }
            });
        }
    }
});
```

Comment: Do you get any error in error console? Try hitting F12 to bring the console up

Comment: have you tried `.prop('checked',false/true)` instead of `_this.attr('checked', '');`?

Comment: Also check this related answer http://stackoverflow.com/questions/426258/how-do-i-check-a-checkbox-with-jquery-or-javascript?rq=1

Comment: @Amitd - I have, but there is no error.
actually, it will place the checked="checked" on the HTML element, but the checkbox still remain unchecked.

Comment: @AntonBelev - yes, but still not working.

Comment: @AntonBelev - now I have tried it and it works fine. hmm. But anyways thank you for the suggestion..

right now, issue is solved. thanks guys..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I had problems (strange anomalies) with checking and unchecking checkboxes with JQuery. I was using `.attr` and `.removeAttr` and when I changed it to `.prop('checked',false/true)` I resolved the problem.

> Before jQuery 1.6, the .attr() method sometimes took property values into account when retrieving some attributes, which could cause inconsistent behavior. As of jQuery 1.6, the .prop() method provides a way to explicitly retrieve property values, while .attr() retrieves attributes.
>   [Reference:](http://api.jquery.com/prop/)

Note you should be using `JQuery 1.6 +`.

Comment: I have tried this .prop() yesterday, and it is not working. But I have tried it now, and it works well. Maybe it has something to do with my codes.. but right now it is solved.. using .prop(), thank you..

Answer (score 2):

```
var statusCheck = $('.status-box')

$.ajax({
        url     : 'sample/url',
        type    : 'POST',
        data    : { user_id: ids, status: statusVal },
        success : function( response ) {
            if( response == 'ok' ) {
                $.each(statusCheck, function(){
                    var _this    = $(this);

                    if( _this.is(':checked') ) {
                        _this.removeAttr('checked');
                    } else {
                        _this.attr('checked', 'checked');
                             // ...............^ here ^
                    }
                });
            }
        }
    });
```

Try this: `_this.attr('checked', 'checked');`

Also `.prop()` from this [Link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/426258/how-do-i-check-a-checkbox-with-jquery-or-javascript?rq=1) might do the magic ;)